# Snakemake: scatter-gather batch processing

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a large number of molecules for virtual screening and I'm utilizing Snakemake to automate the generation of reports for each input molecule:

```py
# Define 1 million reports for processing
REPORTS = expand("reports/{molecule}.report", molecule=range(0, 10**6))

rule all:
    input: REPORTS

# Parallel execution of virtual screening
rule virtual_screening:
    input: "molecules/{molecule}.mol2"
    output: "reports/{molecule}.report"
    shell: "do_screening {input} {output}"
```

However, this method triggers the `do_screening` command one million times. In contrast, `do_screening` can be more efficient by being executed only once in a batch mode:

```
$ do_screening --batch input_molecules.txt --outdir results/
```

In this mode, `input_molecules.txt` is a file listing the paths of input molecules.

I need guidance on how to:

- Identify all `{molecule}.report` files **missing** in the DAG as new molecules are constantly added to generate new reports.
- Divide the missing molecules into `N` batches (e.g., `input_molecules_1.txt`, `input_molecules_2.txt`, ...) for screening.
- Execute `N` instances of `do_screening` in parallel for batched processing.

I've reviewed the [Snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html), but I'm struggling to understand how to efficiently apply concepts like input functions, the scatter-gather pattern, and arbitrary Python `run` directives to solve my problem. Any expert advice would be much appreciated.